# Error using Hilt to inject OkHttpClient into AppGlideModule

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-glide, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject an OkHttpClient into an AppGlideModule using Hilt.

My network module provides the http client:

```
   @Singleton
   @Provides
   fun provideOkHttpClient(
      tokenInterceptor: Interceptor
   ): OkHttpClient {
      return OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
         .build()
   }
```

Trying to inject into AppGlideModule:

```
@GlideModul
@Excludes(OkHttpLibraryGlideModule::class)
class MyGlideModule: AppGlideModule() {

    @Inject lateinit var httpClient: OkHttpClient

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.replace(GlideUrl::class.java, InputStream::class.java, OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(httpClient))

    }
}
```

However when glide is initialed the http client is not injected as I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit
> property httpClient has not been initialized

I have also tried to use constructor injection with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hilt does not know how to provide dependencies to `MyGlideModule` because there is no entry point. You need to make one for the class.

```kotlin
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
// entry point for MyGlideModule
interface MyGlideEntryPoint {
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient
}
```

In `registerComponents`, the application context will be provided as a parameter. Using the context, you can get the entry point to inject dependencies you need.

```kotlin
@GlideModule
@Excludes(OkHttpLibraryGlideModule::class)
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        // get MyGlideEntryPoint from context
        val entryPoint = EntryPoints.get(context, MyGlideEntryPoint::class.java)

        // get HttpClient from the entry point
        val httpClient = entryPoint.provideOkHttpClient()

        registry.replace(
            GlideUrl::class.java,
            InputStream::class.java,
            OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(httpClient)
        )
    }

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface MyGlideEntryPoint {
        fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient
    }
}
```

If you need more info about Hilt's entry point, see https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points

Answer (score -1):

Are you providing the `Interceptor` object you are using in your network module? If not then hilt would have no way of providing the OkHttpClient instance you need.

I believe it should work properly after creating a new function for `provideTokenInterceptor`

Comment: I am providing the interceptor object.  Every other place I inject the http client it works.  Just not in the AppGlideModule